# Property observers not working when assigning properties in init

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, observers

i am amazed by this issue i have check. the constructor is called and vale of Start time as well updated but its never called did set closure.

```
class DesignatedLevels{
    var _startTime:AppTime?
    var _endTime:AppTime?
    var startTime:String?
    {
        didSet{
            _startTime = AppTime(time: self.startTime!)
        }
    }
    var endTime:String?
    {
        didSet{
            _endTime = AppTime(time: self.endTime!)
        }
    }



    init(dataJS:[String:Any])
    {
        id = dataJS["id"] as? String
        name = dataJS["name"] as? String
        userName = dataJS["userName"] as? String
        startTime = dataJS["startTime"] as? String ?? ""
        endTime = dataJS["endTime"] as? String   ?? ""



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Property observers are only called after an object is initialized, meaning any assignments within `init` will not execute code in `willGet`, `didGet`, `didSet` or `willSet`. It's possible to wrap your assignments in a `defer` block which will execute immediately after `init` exits. For example:

```
    init(dataJS:[String:Any])
    {
        defer {
            id = dataJS["id"] as? String
            name = dataJS["name"] as? String
            userName = dataJS["userName"] as? String
            startTime = dataJS["startTime"] as? String ?? ""
            endTime = dataJS["endTime"] as? String   ?? ""
        }
    }
```

Would cause property observers to execute because the `defer` block executes after the object is `init`ed.